# Creating a Map between String and List of Strings

Tags: apex, map

how can i create a MAP for a string and a List of Strings?
 It should be mostly look like `Map<String,List<string>>?`

```
public class Tough {
public static void Times()
{
    Map <string,List<String>> strMap = new Map <string,List<String>>();


        for(integer i=0;i<=7;i++)
        {
            List<String> strlist = new List<String>();
            for(integer y=0;y<=7;y++)
            {
                strlist.add ('BMW' );//add values into the list
                strlist.add ('Mercedes');
                strlist.add ('Audi' );
                strlist.add ('Ferrari');
                strlist.add ('Toyota');
            }

            strMap.put ('Usa'   , strlist);
            strMap.put ('India' , strlist);
            strMap.put ('UK'   , strlist);
            strMap.put ('Italy' , strlist);
            strMap.put ('Germany'   , strlist);
        }
            for(integer t=0;t<5; t++)
            {
                system.debug(strMap);
            }   
}
```

}

can anyone help me with this

[image]

Comment: your question is not clear after your update what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an example of code for your purpose.

```
//declare a map
Map <String,List<String>> strMap = new Map <String,List<String>>();
for (integer i=0; i <5; i++)
{
       //declare list of String variable.
       List<String> strlist = new List<String>();
       for ( Integer y=0; y <5; y++)
       { 
           strlist.add ('abc' + y); //add values into the list
       } 
       strMap.put ('x' + i, strlist); //add values into the map   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is correct. The syntax for map of String to List of Strings would be,

`Map<String, List<String>> mapOfStringToStrings = new Map<String, List<String>>();`

Note than, here only map is created. So if you do `mapOfStringToStrings.get('somevalue')` it will return `null`. You should handle this and initialize to a valid `List` before consuming that list.